# Postgres INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I'm working on a Postgres script and running into this error. In short, I'm trying to upsert a record.

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"

I'm not sure what syntax I am missing. Could anyone help?

This is what SELECT version() returns

> PostgreSQL 12.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit`

```
WITH test_insert AS (
INSERT INTO
    test.temp_customer(
        company_name,
        customer_type,
        email
    )

SELECT
    customer_company_name,
    customer_type,
    email
FROM
    test_table
WHERE
    customer_contact = true

ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE
SET 
company_name = EXCLUDED.company_name,
customer_type = EXCLUDED.customer_type,
email = EXCLUDED.email
)
```

Comment: Remove the `WITH test_insert AS (` and the final `)`

Comment: But your statement doesn't make sense because you don't even provide a value for `email` - so how can there be a conflict?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name apologies, I have a lot more fields in the insert statement, but removed them so the code example is concise. I will add it back is so the example makes more sense. Thank you for your time and effort!